# How did the aliens cheer when they didn't have vocal cords?

Tags: plot-explanation, independence-day-resurgence

In the first Independence Day (1996), Dr. Okun clearly states that the aliens have no means of oral communication: No vocal cords.

However, in Independence Day 2: Resurgence (2016), there is a scene where hundreds of aliens are heard "cheering" in the trailer:

How is it physiologically possible?

Or is it a retcon? Or a sizable plot hole?

Comment: The aliens in the prison cells were being kept with the exosuits/armor on. Perhaps the aliens themselves don't have vocal cords but the suits have speakers. It is also possible the cells included systems to pick up on either telepathic transmissions from the aliens or other kinds of transmissions from the suits.

Comment: You might remember that they made sounds in the first film, too. But screaming is not talking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of creatures have no vocal chords but make sounds. If I remember correctly someone confuses screams of pain for what is in fact celebration in the film. Could still be a mistake in writing but dinosaurs are depicted as growling/roaring but science has never insinuated they have vocal chords or can speak. I can't claim to be an authority on aliens though. I haven't met any...yet.

Comment: ...that you know of.